# Get phone name and model

Tags: java-me

How can I get the phone name, model, and firmware versioan in an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best bet is `System.getProperty("microedition.platform")`.  That provides all the information you need on some handsets such as Nokias or SonyEricssons, but on some handsets it just returns "J2ME".

An alternative could be to make an HTTP request to a server somewhere, and have the server check the user-agent for you.